# php crawler detection

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a sitemap.php which acts differently depending on who is looking.

I want to redirect crawlers to my sitemap.xml, as that will be the most updated page and will contain all the info they need, but I want my regular readers to be show a html sitemap on the php page.

This will all be controlled from within the php header, and I've found [this code](http://www.cult-f.net/2008/05/07/detect-crawlers-with-php/) on the web which by the looks of it should work, but it's not. Can anyone help crack this for me?

```
function getIsCrawler($userAgent) {
    $crawlers = 'firefox|Google|msnbot|Rambler|Yahoo|AbachoBOT|accoona|' .
    'AcioRobot|ASPSeek|CocoCrawler|Dumbot|FAST-WebCrawler|' .
    'GeonaBot|Gigabot|Lycos|MSRBOT|Scooter|AltaVista|IDBot|eStyle|Scrubby';
    $isCrawler = (preg_match("/$crawlers/i", $userAgent) > 0);
    return $isCrawler;
}

$iscrawler = getIsCrawler($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

if ($isCrawler) {
    header('Location: http://www.website.com/sitemap.xml');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "not crawler!";
}
```

It looks pretty simple, but as you can see i've added firefox into the agent list, and sure enough I'm not being redirected..

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code:

```
$crawler = getIsCrawler($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

should be

```
$isCrawler = getIsCrawler($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

If you develop with notices on you'll catch these errors much more easily.

Also, you probable want to `exit` after the `header`

**Warning**: *Cloaking* can get you in trouble with search providers. [This article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) explains why.

Comment: Doh! can't believe I missed that. Good suggestion on notices too, shall do that.

Answer (score 1):

http://develobert.blogspot.com/2008/11/php-robot-check.html

Comment: Nice one - that's a neat way of doing it. Unfortunately this site is being developed on IIS not apache - so no htaccess or anything like it which I can use :x